# How to randomly sort (scramble) an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, shuffle

I'd like to have my array items scrambled.
Something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [2,1,3,4]
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [3,1,2,4]
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [4,2,3,1]
```

and so on, randomly

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Built in now:

```
[1,2,3,4].shuffle => [2, 1, 3, 4]
[1,2,3,4].shuffle => [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: And if you want to implement it yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: Or if you want it for Ruby < 1.9:
require 'backports'

Comment: Looks like it's in Ruby 1.8.7 too.

Comment: Just wanted to add: if you want to affect the collection add a `!` after the call to shuffle. Without the `!` the shuffled array is returned, and ripe for a assignment.

Answer (score 28):

For ruby 1.8.6 (which does not have shuffle built in):

```
array.sort_by { rand }
```

Comment: @Josh: The page you linked to describes an entirely different algorithm. Note that ruby's `sort_by` function does not work like javascript's sort function (or ruby's sort function for that matter), which only cares whether the computed number is less than zero, zero or greater than zero. Instead `sort_by` remembers the computed value for each item and then sorts the items by that value. So in this case each item is assigned a random number and then the array is sorted by those random numbers.

Comment: With a large size array this sort by the random numbers for each item might take too long (O(NLogN), we could do it in a linear time if we generate a random number from the previous items we have shuffled and then swap as the iterator increment.

Answer (score 8):

For ruby 1.8.6 as sepp2k's example, but you still want use "shuffle" method.

```
class Array
  def shuffle
    sort_by { rand }
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].shuffle #=> [2,4,3,1]
[1,2,3,4].shuffle #=> [4,2,1,3]
```

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Code from the [Backports Gem](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) for just the Array for Ruby 1.8.6. Ruby 1.8.7 or higher is built in.

```
class Array
  # Standard in Ruby 1.8.7+. See official documentation[http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Array.html]
  def shuffle
    dup.shuffle!
  end unless method_defined? :shuffle

  # Standard in Ruby 1.8.7+. See official documentation[http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Array.html]
  def shuffle!
    size.times do |i|
      r = i + Kernel.rand(size - i)
      self[i], self[r] = self[r], self[i]
    end
    self
  end unless method_defined? :shuffle!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby Facets](http://facets.rubyforge.org) library of extensions has a [`Random`](http://facets.rubyforge.org/apidoc/api/more/classes/Random.html) module which provides useful methods including `shuffle` and `shuffle!` to a bunch of core classes including `Array`, `Hash` and `String`.

Just be careful if you're using Rails as I experienced some nasty clashes in the way its monkeypatching clashed with Rails'...