# quick random row selection in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, random

I have a table in postgres that contains couple of millions  of rows. I have checked on the internet and I found the following

```
SELECT myid FROM mytable ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

It works, but it's really slow... is there another way to make that query, or a direct way to select a random row without reading all the table? By the way 'myid' is an integer but it can be an empty field.

Comment: If you want to select multiple random rows, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8674718/247696

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You might want to experiment with `OFFSET`, as in

```
SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET floor(random() * N) LIMIT 1;
```

The `N` is the number of rows in `mytable`. You may need to first do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` to figure out the value of `N`.

**Update** (by Antony Hatchkins)

You must use `floor` here:

```
SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET floor(random() * N) LIMIT 1;
```

Consider a table of 2 rows; `random()*N` generates `0 <= x < 2` and for example `SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET 1.7 LIMIT 1;` returns 0 rows because of implicit rounding to nearest int.

Comment: make It sense to use a N less than `SELECT COUNT(*)`?, I mean, not use all the values in the table but only a part of them?

Comment: @Juan That depends on your requirements.

Comment: using the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with different values of N give the same cost for the query, then I guess is better to go for the maximum value of N.

Comment: see a bugfix in my answer below

Comment: This has an off by one error. It will never return the first row and will generate an error 1/COUNT(*) because it will try to return the row after the last row.

Comment: What if N = total number of records? You will be scanning the whole table.

Answer (score 79):

PostgreSQL 9.5 introduced a new approach for much faster sample selection: [TABLESAMPLE](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/)

The syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(percentage);
SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(percentage);
```

This is not the optimal solution if you want only one row selected, because you need to know the COUNT of the table to calculate the exact percentage.

To avoid a slow COUNT and use fast TABLESAMPLE for tables from 1 row to billions of rows, you can do:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.000001) LIMIT 1;
 -- if you got no result:
 SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.00001) LIMIT 1;
 -- if you got no result:
 SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.0001) LIMIT 1;
 -- if you got no result:
 SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(0.001) LIMIT 1;
 ...
```

This might not look so elegant, but probably is faster than any of the other answers.

To decide whether you want to use BERNULLI oder SYSTEM, read about the difference at https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/

Comment: This is much much faster and easier than any other answer -- this one should be at the top.

Comment: Why can't you just use a subquery to get the count? `SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(SELECT 1/COUNT(*) FROM my_table) LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: @machineghost "To avoid a slow COUNT..." ... If your data is so small, that you can count in reasonable time, go for it! :-)

Comment: @machineghost Use `SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'my_table'` for count estimation.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil very good input!
To ensure that the estimation is not outdated, it has to bee VACUUM ANALYZEd recently.. but a good database should be properly analyzed anyway.. And it all depends on the specific use-case. Usually huge tables don't grow so fast... Thanks!

Comment: @machineghost You need extra brackets, and cast the 1 to a `float`y kind of thing so you get a fractional number returned: `SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM((SELECT 1::double precision/COUNT(*) FROM my_table)) LIMIT 1;`

Comment: `ERROR:  TABLESAMPLE clause can only be applied to tables and materialized views`. I was trying to use this in a CTE on a subset of one table's data. Which makes it [pretty limited](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258272/92346) in my opinion.

Answer (score 36):

I tried this with a subquery and it worked fine. Offset, at least in Postgresql v8.4.4 works fine.

```
select * from mytable offset random() * (select count(*) from mytable) limit 1 ;
```

Comment: In fact, v8.4 is essential for this to work, doesn't work for <=8.3.

Comment: see a bugfix in my answer below

Answer (score 32):

You need to use `floor`:

```
SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET floor(random()*N) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Consider a table of 2 rows; `random()*N` generates 0 <= x < 2 and 
for example `SELECT myid FROM mytable OFFSET 1.7 LIMIT 1;` returns 0 rows because of implicit rounding to nearest int.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you want to use a higher LIMIT... I need to get 3 items so I need to use the ORDER BY RANDOM() syntax.

Comment: Three consecutive queries will still be faster than one `order by random()`, approximately as `3*O(N) < O(NlogN)` - reallife figures will be slightly different due to indices.

Comment: My problem is that the 3 items need to be distinct and a `WHERE myid NOT IN (1st-myid)` and `WHERE myid NOT IN (1st-myid, 2nd-myid)` wouldn't work since the decision is made by the OFFSET. Hmmm... I guess I could reduce N by 1 and 2 in the second and third SELECT.

Comment: Could you or anyone expand this answer with an answer to ***why*** I need to use `floor()`? What advantage does it offer?

Comment: `floor(random()*N)` is guaranteed to be 0..N-1 and never N.

Comment: This is the correct solution, without floor with N=1, I get numbers between 0 and 1. Sometimes this will give me no rows and sometimes it will give me a single row, I'm assuming because postgres implicitly rounds to the nearest int with OFFSET.

Comment: I found out about this the hard way, this should be added to the accepted answer. +1

Comment: @Hjalmar that's why I usually read all the answers. It's a common thing here on SO that the accepted answer is not the best one. Added to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Check this link out for some different options.
http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/

**Update:** (A.Hatchkins)

The summary of the (very) long article is as follows.

The author lists four approaches:

1) `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;`   -- slow

2) `ORDER BY id where id>=random()*N LIMIT 1` -- nonuniform if there're gaps

3) random column -- needs to be updated every now and then

4) custom [random aggregate](http://web.archive.org/web/20080214235745/http://www.powerpostgresql.com/Random_Aggregate) -- cunning method, could be slow: random() needs to be generated N times

and suggests to improve method #2 by using

5) `ORDER BY id where id=random()*N LIMIT 1`
with subsequent requeries if the result is empty.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't cover OFFSET? Using an ORDER is out of the question just to get a random row. Fortunately, OFFSET is well covered in the answers.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest and fastest way to fetch random row is to use the `tsm_system_rows` extension :

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tsm_system_rows;
```

Then you can select the exact number of rows you want :

```
SELECT myid  FROM mytable TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(1);
```

This is available with PostgreSQL 9.5 and later.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tsm-system-rows.html

Comment: Fair warning, this isn't completely random. On smaller tables, I've had it always return the first rows in order.

Comment: yes this is clearly explained in documentation (link above) : « Like the built-in SYSTEM sampling method, SYSTEM_ROWS performs block-level sampling, so that the sample is not completely random but may be subject to clustering effects, especially if only a small number of rows are requested. » .  If you have a small dataset, the `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;` should be fast enough.

Comment: I saw that. Just wanted to make it clear to anyone who doesn't click the link or if the link dies in the future.

Comment: Also worth noting that this will only work for selecting random rows out of a table and THEN filtering, as opposed/compared to running a query and then picking one or some records at random.

Answer (score 4):

I've came up with a very fast solution without `TABLESAMPLE`. Much faster than `OFFSET random()*N LIMIT 1`. It doesn't even require table count.

The idea is to create an expression index with random but predictable data, for example `md5(primary key)`.

Here is a test with 1M rows sample data:

```
create table randtest (id serial primary key, data int not null);

insert into randtest (data) select (random()*1000000)::int from generate_series(1,1000000);

create index randtest_md5_id_idx on randtest (md5(id::text));

explain analyze
select * from randtest where md5(id::text)>md5(random()::text)
order by md5(id::text) limit 1;
```

Result:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6.219..6.220 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using randtest_md5_id_idx on randtest  (cost=0.42..84040.42 rows=333333 width=8) (actual time=6.217..6.217 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (md5((id)::text) > md5((random())::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1831
 Total runtime: 6.245 ms
```

This query can sometimes (with about 1/Number_of_rows probability) return 0 rows, so it needs to be checked and rerun. Also probabilities aren't exactly the same - some rows are more probable than others.

For comparison:

```
explain analyze SELECT id FROM randtest OFFSET random()*1000000 LIMIT 1;
```

Results vary widely, but can be pretty bad:

```
 Limit  (cost=1442.50..1442.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=179.183..179.184 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on randtest  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.016..134.835 rows=915702 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 179.211 ms
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Fast, yes. Truly random, no. An md5 values that happens to be the next greater value after another existing value has a very slim chance to be picked, while values after a big gap in the number space have a much bigger chance (bigger by the number of possible values in between). The resulting distribution is not random.

Comment: very interesting, could it work in a usecase of a lottery-like query: the query must look into all available tickets and randomly return only ONE single ticket. also can I use a pessimistic lock (select...for update) with your technique?

Comment: For anything lottery related you should really use fair and cryptographically secure random sampling - for example pick a random number between 1 and max(id) until you find existing id. The method from this answer is neither fair nor secure - it's fast. Usable for things like 'get random 1% of rows to test something on', or 'show random 5 entries'.

Answer (score 0):

I added a randomly generated number to each row and generate a random number in my programming language that is added to each row.
When calling, I pass a random number to the query (in this case 0.27)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (SELECT id, random FROM t where <condition> and random >= 0.27 ORDER BY random LIMIT 1)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, random FROM t where <condition> and random < 0.27 ORDER BY random DESC LIMIT 1)
) as results
ORDER BY abs(0.27-random) LIMIT 1;
```

(Query taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102824/is-there-a-postgres-closest-operator))

If you have an index here on your the rows in your condition and the random row (containing the random numbers), I get a result in 6 ms on my 8.5 million row table. This is orders of magnitude faster than using anything like order by random().

To improve randomness, you can also generate a new random number for each result you have hit. (Without this some number will occur more often than others.)

Unlike TABLESAMPLE this also supports conditions.