# how to get nearest value from database in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, select

I am using `mySQL` and `CodeIgniter`. I have some floating point numbers in my database such as

- 8.3456
- 8.5555
- 4.5556

I want to...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = $myvalue
```

but I can't use `value = $myvalue` in my SELECT query because `$myvalue` is not exactly equal to database values. I need to get the nearest value to `$myvalue` from database.

If `$myvalue` is 5 I want to select the value `4.5556`.

How can I do this in mySQL?

Comment: if you have a few rows then the answers towards the top will be sufficient - however if you have millions of rows i would not recommend them as they will scan the whole table - instead see my answer at the bottom (trade-off being readability as the query is much longer - but much faster too)

Answer (score 24):

```
select * 
from table 
order by abs(value - $myvalue)
limit 1
```

Comment: Probably does a (slow) table scan.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you have a 10% tolerance (+/-) you could try something like:

```
select * from table 
where value >= ($myvalue * .9) and value <= ($myvalue * 1.1) 
order by abs(value - $myvalue) limit 1
```

Slightly updated stealing from others - this should return the nearest result in the assumed tolerance range. (Also, I just noticed the where was incorrect, apologies - now it should work).

Comment: What if the nearest $myvalue is more than your arbitrary % away from any value?

Comment: The original requirement is not very clear. Of course if there is no "accepted range" you can say that 10000000000 is close enough to "1", assuming there is nothing better in your DB. In this case you can drop the "where" part.

Comment: Note that this will fail if `$Myvalue` is 0. If you really want to do this, you need to add `OR (($myvalue >= (value * .9)) AND ($myvalue <= (value * 1.1)))`

Comment: This will not show nearest value if he put 6 for example -> however you were on the right track with the >= and < so a +1 from me (and a +1 for not using `ABS` on a whole table!)-> anyone looking who sees this please see my answer bottom that will give a fast, correct result.

Answer (score 16):

```
(
select   *
from     table
where    value >= $myvalue
order by value asc
limit 1
)
union
(
select   *
from     table
where    value < $myvalue
order by value desc
limit 1
)
order by abs(value - $myvalue)
limit 1
```

This may look counter-intuitive but the speed will be greater than the other queries shown so far.

This is due to the fact that a `greater than` and `less than` query is quicker.

Then doing an `ABS` on two values is nothing.

This will give you the quickest return in a single query I can think of.

Doing an `ABS` on a whole table will be slow as it will scan the whole table.

Comment: Looks like the best answer so far

Comment: This is great! For even better performance (~50%), replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`. (I deleted my previous comment: union is the fastest possible way)

Answer (score 3):

Take the first value from the following:

```
select * from table order by abs(value - $myvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the largest value similar to $val:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val <= $val ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 1
```

Get the smallest value similar to $val:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val >= $val ORDER BY val LIMIT 1
```

Get the closest value similar to $val in either direction:

```
SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY abs(val - $val) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using the browsers geolocations and trying to find a closest city/state based on the coordinates I had in a table.

table structure:

```
id    zipcode    city_state   lat    lon
1     12345      Example, GA  85.3   -83.2
```

Recommend testing this vigorously before using -- probably needs some tweaks, but I came up with this as a start

```
SELECT city_state, 
   zipcode, 
   ( Abs( lat - -33.867886 ) 
     + Abs( lon - -63.987) ) AS distance
FROM   zipcodes 
ORDER  BY distance 
LIMIT  1;
```

For laravel users:

```
$city = Zipcodes::selectRaw
    ('city_state, zipcode,  ( ABS( lat - ? ) + ABS( lon - ?) ) AS distance', [$lat, $lon])
        ->orderBy('distance')
        ->first();

echo $city->city_state
```

Hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ABS(value - '$myvalue') LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think your database will probably do a full table scan for solutions that involve `abs`, so they will be (very) slow once your table grows. A fast-running solution may be found in this [earlier thread specific to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102824/is-there-a-postgres-closest-operator/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT number, ABS( number - 2500 ) AS distance
FROM numbers
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 6
```

[Selecting closest values in MySQL](http://www.techfounder.net/2009/02/02/selecting-closest-values-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,abs((columnname -Yourvalue)) as near
  FROM table
 WHERE order by near limit 0,1
```

Answer (score -1):

Read this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

but your select would look like this

```
select value from table where ROUND(value) = $myvalue
```

Comment: What if the nearest `$myvalue` is more than 1 away from any value?

Comment: @Bohemian - at some point your going to need a cut off point for matching the value

Comment: @Bohemian, no you don't that depends entirely on your application, and **if** you need a cutoff, it should always be a percentage of the original values. What if you're not dealing with `8.12`, but with `15,481,254,454,875,544,545.1` instead?

Comment: The question is clear: "Pick the *closest* value". It doesn't say anything about *how far away* the value is... could be 1000 away. Your answer is, quite simply, "wrong".