# Nearest Value in the Database table

Tags: php

I want to Find the nearest numeric match in a database to what a user has inputed in php. The Database value can be multipled with an integer to find the near value to user Input.

For Ex:
Database has the following Pallets:

```
950, 900, 1070
```

User Input a Value: 2000

Not the System should check:

```
950 * 2 = 1900
900 *2 = 1800
1070 * 2 = 2140
```

So the nearest value to 2000 is 1900. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get nearest value from database in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269243/how-to-get-nearest-value-from-database-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, also replace 2000 with user input.

```
SELECT your_column, abs( 2000 MOD your_column) ) as diff
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY diff
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: But the number 2 may be variable i.e it can either be 3 etc.

Comment: Hi @tan, Thanks for the query. It has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT your_column, abs( $_POST['form_field_name']-(your_column*2) ) as setcustomcolumn FROM `rablename` order by columnname LIMIT 1
```

Comment: give some explanation for your answer