# Closest value within tolerance band for multiple ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for something that, given a table like:

```
| channelid  | curveid  | xvalue   |
| 1          | 21       | 179.9216 |
| 1          | 21       | 180.4314 |
| 1          | 21       | 180.6528 |
| 1          | 21       | 180.9251 |
| 1          | 21       | 181.1334 |
| 1          | 21       | 181.4417 |
| 2          | 21       | 179.9513 |
| 2          | 21       | 180.1612 |
| 2          | 21       | 180.2022 |
| 2          | 21       | 180.8762 |
| 2          | 21       | 181.1331 |
| 2          | 21       | 181.2842 |
| 1          | 22       | 179.9213 |
| 1          | 22       | 180.4415 |
| 1          | 22       | 180.6226 |
| 1          | 22       | 180.9758 |
| 1          | 22       | 181.1639 |
| 1          | 22       | 181.4212 |
| 2          | 22       | 179.9715 |
| 2          | 22       | 180.1513 |
| 2          | 22       | 180.2326 |
| 2          | 22       | 180.8265 |
| 2          | 22       | 181.1437 |
| 2          | 22       | 181.2442 |
```

returns me the closest xvalue to a value found for each unique channelid curveid combination.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102824/is-there-a-postgres-closest-operator/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269243/how-to-get-nearest-value-from-database-in-mysql). With this I can find the closest value in total. However I need help extending it so it returns the closest to each unique combination.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE xvalue >= ($myvalue - .5) AND xvalue <= ($myvalue + .5) 
ORDER by abs(xvalue - $myvalue)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this in Postgres uses `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (channelid, curveid) t.*
FROM table  
ORDER by channelid, curveid, abs(xvalue - $myvalue);
```

If you know the nearest value is within 0.5 of `$myvalue` for all combinations you want, then you can add your `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a group by

```
select channelid, curveid,min(abs(xvalue - $myvalue)) 
from table
WHERE xvalue >= ($myvalue + .5) AND xvalue <= ($myvalue - .5) 
group by channelid, curveid 
ORDER by   min(abs(xvalue - $myvalue)) asc
```

and if you need  also the related  xvalue

```
select table.*, t.min_diff  from table  
inner join  (

  select channelid, curveid,min(abs(xvalue - $myvalue))  min_diff
  from table  
  WHERE xvalue >= ($myvalue + .5) AND xvalue <= ($myvalue - .5) 
  group by channelid, curveid 
  ORDER by   min(abs(xvalue - $myvalue)) asc 

) t on t.channelid = table.channelid 
      and y.curveid = table.curveid 
        and abs(table.xvalue - $myvalue) = t.min_diff
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `with` to first prepare my data.

```
with min as
   (
     select channelid, curveid, min(abs(xvalue-$myvalue)) mindifference 
     from table group by channelid, curveid
   )
select channelid, curveid, xvalue from min innner join table using (channelid, curveid) where abs(xvalue-$myvalue) = mindifference
```

This has the advantage to see ex-aequo results, and you can easily access the minimum difference in your outer query.