# MySQL - UNION ALL with queries on same table

Tags: mysql, union, alias

I would like to use some query that i found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102824/is-there-a-postgres-closest-operator/) site - I adapted it for my own purposes:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
(
SELECT id, lng FROM stations WHERE lng >= 18.123 ORDER BY lng LIMIT 1
) AS result1
UNION ALL
(
SELECT id, lng FROM stations WHERE lng < 18.123 ORDER BY lng LIMIT 1
) AS result2
)
ORDER BY abs(18.123-lng) LIMIT 1;
```

But I got an error `Syntax error, unexpected AS, expecting UNION_SYM or ')'`

When i try to do it without aliases, I (obviously) keep getting  error `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias`

Could you please help me figure out what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias the outermost table, as such:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    (SELECT id, lng FROM stations WHERE lng >= 18.123 ORDER BY lng LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT id, lng FROM stations WHERE lng < 18.123 ORDER BY lng LIMIT 1)
) AS result12
ORDER BY abs(18.123-lng) LIMIT 1;
```

EDIT: forgot the parentheses around the inner queries.