# Set randomly chosen string as default value in sql column (Postgress)

Tags: postgresql

I have this column on my user table `hat_color` in my PostgreSQL database.

I would like to set a randomly chosen color value as the default value if no value is provided when creating the column.

So the default value should be one of `['red', 'blue', 'green']`

I was thinking something like

```
['red','blue','green'][floor(random() * (h-l+1) + l)::int]::text
```

but that does does not work. Is this possible to do and if so how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142154/postgresql-random-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax:

```sql
(array['red','blue','green'])[floor(random()* 3+ 1)::int]
-- or
('{red,blue,green}'::text[])[floor(random()* 3+ 1)::int]
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/sr1HLl-M)