# How to (or Can I) select a random value from the Postgresql database excluding some particular records?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

Is it possible to randomly select a record from the database excluding some records with particular status?

For eg,

For example, I have a table for storing employee details.

```
id    employeename employeestatus
 1    ab           1
 2    cd           1
 3    ef           2
 4    gh           1
 5    ij           1
```

What I want from the query is to fetch a single random record whose status is not 2. Is it possible to do so? The database I'm using is PostgreSQL 8.4.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY This

```
SELECT * 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  employeestatus != 2 
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this other question on the same topic

[Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

It's tricker than you think (to do efficiently)