# Psycopg2 - return first 1000 results and randomly pick one

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

Hi I have a postgresql "TABLE1" with 2.7 million records. Each record has a field "FIELD1" that may be empty or may have data. I want a SELECT statement or method that a) returns the first 1000 results from TABLE1 with FIELD1 empty, and b) randomly pick one of the records to return to a python variable. Help???

Comment: This question might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql

Comment: You need to define: "empty", "first", your requirements (speed? repeated use?). Please supply a table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For selecting first 1000 result you can use limit in your query

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY id Limit 1000;
```

The result will be a list in python. So you can use python [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#module-random) module to operate on the result list.

Comment: How does postgresql choose the 1000? Is it in order of primary key number? If yes, how can I get 1000 random records?

Comment: You can add ORDER BY clause to query also. I have edited my answer. Default order by has to be primary id but not always guaranted to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

If **performance is not a concern**:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  field1 IS NULL
   ORDER  BY id           --?? unclear from question
   LIMIT  1000
   ) sub
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  1;
```

This returns 1 perfectly random row from the "first" 1000 empty rows.
"Empty" meaning `NULL`, and "first" meaning smallest `id`.

If performance is a concern, you need to be **a lot more specific**.
If your circumstances match, this related answer might of help:
[Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)