# Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, string-concatenation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getParentLtree(parent_id bigint, tbl_name varchar) 
  RETURNS ltree AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   parent_ltree ltree;
BEGIN
-- This works fine:
-- select into parent_ltree l_tree from tbl1 where id = parent_id;

EXECUTE format('select into parent_ltree l_tree from %I
                where id = %I', tbl_name,parent_id);

RETURN parent_ltree;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are 2 issues in above function:

1. `parent_id` is `integer` but it is replaced with quotes? What is the correct format specifier for `int` variables?
2. `select into` does not work with `EXECUTE`? How can I make above commented query to use table name passed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This would be shorter, faster and safer:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_parent_ltree(parent_id bigint, tbl_name regclass
                                          , OUT parent_ltree ltree)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT l_tree FROM %s WHERE id = $1', tbl_name)
   INTO  parent_ltree
   USING parent_id;
END
$func$;
```

#### Why?

Most importantly, use the [**`USING`** clause of `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for parameter values. Don't convert them to `text`, concatenate and interpret them back. That would be slower and error-prone.

Normally you would use the [`%I` specifier with `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for identifiers like the table name. For existing tables, a [`regclass` object-identifier type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) may be even better. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

The [`OUT` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) makes it simpler. Performance is the same.

Don't use unquoted CaMeL case identifiers like `getParentLtree` in Postgres. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: great!, its much better, dont know if 2 answers can be accepted. will use all suggestions, CaMel case was my mistake, came just out of habit I knew postgres will make it lower case and using quotes can only make matters worse.

Comment: what does $1 mean in your select statement ?

Comment: @RonaldDas: It's a parameter for the first value provided with the USING clause. Follow the first link for details.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hey. I try to replicate your answer, but I encountered some issue. Would you like to help me solve it. 
 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166528/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-integer-2-2-with-custom-data-type-while-execu)

Answer (score 5):

Use `%s` for strings. `%I` is for identifiers:

```
select format('select into parent_ltree l_tree from %I  where id = %s', 'tbl1', 1);
                         format                          
---------------------------------------------------------
 select into parent_ltree l_tree from tbl1  where id = 1
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT

PL/pgSQL's `select into` is not the same as Postgresql's `select into`. Use instead `create table as`:

```
create table parent_ltree as 
select l_tree 
from tbl1
where id = 1
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

> Tip: Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, wherein the INTO target is a newly created table. If you want to create a table from a SELECT result inside a PL/pgSQL function, use the syntax CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT.

To `select into` a variable from an `execute` statement:

```
EXECUTE format('select l_tree from %I where id = %s', tbl_name,parent_id) 
into parent_ltree;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks for reply, %s is the correct type specifier,works for issue 1, but for issue 2 result is only one value not a set, since id is unique in this case, how can we read it into a variable rather than a table?

Comment: That works as well, Thanks very much! To summarize your solutions                                                           1. %s for Identifiers                                               2. into should be used outside format function.

Answer (score 2):

Following postgres uses a for loop and variable to creates 10 table starting with prefix 'sbtest' namely sbtest1, sbtest2 ... sbtest10

create_table.sql

```
do $$
    DECLARE myvar integer;
begin
    for myvar in 1..10 loop
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE sbtest%s (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        k INTEGER NOT NULL,
        c CHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        pad CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id))', myvar);
    end loop;
end; $$
```

Run it using psql -U user_name -d database_name -f create_table.sql

```
Example Table  sbtest1 is as
id | k | c | pad
----+---+---+-----
(0 rows)
```

Table "public.sbtest1"
Column |      Type      | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage  | Stats
target | Description
--------+----------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+----------+------
--------+-------------
id     | integer        |           | not null | nextval('sbtest1_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
|
k      | integer        |           | not null |                                     | plain    |
|
c      | character(120) |           | not null |                                     | extended |
|
pad    | character(60)  |           | not null |                                     | extended |
|
Indexes:
"sbtest1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Access method: heap