# PostgreSQL 9.3 trigger function to insert into table with parameterized name

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to dynamically partition log entries in Postgres. I have 53 child tables (1 for each week's worth of log entries), and would like to route INSERTs to a child table using a trigger.

I run the function with `INSERT INTO log5 VALUES (NEW.*)`, and it works.

I run the function with the `EXECUTE` statement instead, and it fails. Within the `EXECUTE` statement, it's recognizing `NEW` as a table name and not a variable passed to the trigger function. Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks!

**The error:**

> QUERY: INSERT INTO log5 VALUES (NEW.*)
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function log_roll_test() line 6 at EXECUTE statement
>   ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new" SQL state: 42P01

**My function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION log_roll_test() RETURNS trigger AS $body$
DECLARE t text;
BEGIN
    t := 'log' || extract(week FROM NEW.updt_ts); --child table name
    --INSERT INTO log5 VALUES (NEW.*);
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I VALUES (NEW.*);', t);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**My trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_roll_test
BEFORE INSERT ON log FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_roll_test();
```

Comment: `NEW` isn't recognised, because `EXECUTE` cannot refer to outer variables. Try using the `USING` clause. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks! I tried that already and it doesn't work. It passes the NEW record to the statement, and the EXECUTE statement treats that as a string. I.e., '(value1, value2, value3,,,)'. Postgres doesn't like the commas next to each other, and it doesn't like quotes around the values. I would need to do a regexp_replace to modify the string, and I'd really like to avoid that for performance reasons.

Comment: I've tried about everything, BTW. Pretty close to just giving up and writing a trigger with a CASE WHEN statement (53 lines) and writing a pgScript to create 53 separate trigger functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION log_roll_test()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT ($1).*'     -- !
                , to_char(NEW.updt_ts, '"log"WW'))   -- child table name
   USING NEW;  -- !
   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;
```

You cannot reference `NEW` inside the query string. `NEW` is visible in the function body, but not inside `EXECUTE` environment. The best solution is to pass values in the `USING` clause.

I also substituted the equivalent `to_char(NEW.updt_ts, '"log"WW')` for the table name. [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) is faster and simpler here.

Comment: Thank you Erwin!!! Simple and elegant solution. I'm gonna use %I.%I in the format() statement so I can add a schema qualifier. It works great and will make the trigger function work for multiple log tables.

Comment: @DavidWillis: Where does the schema name come from? For a static value `%s` is good enough. `%I` is only necessary to sanitize dynamic values. If schema and tablename are dynamic, [a cast to `regclass` would be an alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349). [Another related answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)

Comment: Good links. The schema name is static. I ended up casting tg_table_name to regclass. Goal was to get one simple trigger function working for multiple log tables, and I think I'm there. Thanks for the help!