# Casting issue in call of custom aggregate function in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection, dynamic-sql

I am trying to make a check function which checks whether a `tsrange` is contained within an another one. Consider the [**complete example in this fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2fba1cbe2befa0535f99c0461c344405).

The last section is doing the "magic", here is an MVP of the functions.
An actual execution can be found above in the example.

```
-- Setting up init stuff
CREATE TABLE country(entity_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, valid tsrange, registration tsrange);
CREATE TABLE airport(entity_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, valid tsrange, registration tsrange,
country_key bigint references country (entity_id));


-- persisting data into tables
INSERT INTO country 
VALUES(1,'[2016-06-22 19:10:25-07, 2019-01-01 00:00:00)', tsrange(now()::timestamp, '9999-01-01 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO airport VALUES(1,'[2018-06-22 19:10:25-07, 2020-01-01 00:00:00)', tsrange(now()::timestamp, '9999-01-01 00:00:00'), 1);

-- range_merge wrapper
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE range_merge(anyrange)
(
    sfunc = range_merge,
    stype = anyrange
);


-- Aggregate function for aggregating all validity periods from select statement. 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_validity(entity_name regclass, entry bigint) returns tsrange AS
$$
DECLARE
    result tsrange;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('select range_merge(valid) from %I where entity_id = %s', entity_name, entry) into result;
   return result;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


- Detect integrity breach function 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach(altered_table_name text, entity_ids bigint[])  
RETURNS TABLE(
       source_entity text,
       source_entry_id bigint,
       source_entry_validity tsrange,
       is_included_in_timeline boolean,
       aggregated_foreing_entry_validity tsrange,
       foreing_entry_id bigint,
       foreing_entity text,
       is_reference_ingoing boolean
      )
AS $$
DECLARE
    foreign_key  record;
    is_reference_ingoing boolean;
BEGIN

    FOR foreign_key  IN (
        --  Using the information schema from postgres, all constraints of type 
        --  FOREIGN_KEY, is extracted. For each of the foreing key constraint, the 
        --  source_table and foreing_table which is linked by this constraint is then extracted.  
        --  to ensure both ingoing references and outgoing references are extracted from this query, is
        --  condition provided as such that either the source_table = altered_table_name OR foreing_table_name = altered_table_name||'_registration'
        SELECT
            tc.table_name AS source_table, 
            kcu.column_name as column_attribute,
            ccu.table_name AS foreign_table
        FROM 
            information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
            JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
            ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
            JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
            ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
        WHERE 
            constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' and 
            (ccu.table_name = altered_table_name OR tc.table_name = altered_table_name) and
            ccu.column_name != 'row_id' and 
            kcu.column_name != 'entity_id') 
    LOOP
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lookup_breach;
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TEMP TABLE lookup_breach ON COMMIT DROP AS
                       SELECT '||foreign_key.source_table||'.entity_id AS source_entry_id, -- The Id of the source entry
                    '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||' AS foreing_entry_id, -- The id of the foreing entry
                    '||foreign_key.source_table||'.valid AS source_entry_valid, -- the validity period of the source entry
                    aggregate_validity('||foreign_key.foreign_table||', '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||') AS foreing_entry_valid, -- the validity period of the foreing entry
                    aggregate_validity('||foreign_key.foreign_table||', '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||') <@ '||foreign_key.source_table||'.valid as in_lifespan
                    FROM '||foreign_key.foreign_table||', '||foreign_key.source_table||'
                    WHERE '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||' = ANY($1)
                    AND '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||' = '||foreign_key.foreign_table||'_registration.entity_id
                    AND '||foreign_key.source_table||'.registration @> now()::timestamp
                    GROUP BY '||foreign_key.source_table||'.'||foreign_key.column_attribute||', 
                    '||foreign_key.source_table||'.entity_id,'||foreign_key.source_table||'.valid,
                    '||foreign_key.foreign_table||'.valid' ) using entity_ids;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT foreign_key.source_table::text, lookup_breach.source_entry_id, lookup_breach.source_entry_valid, lookup_breach.in_lifespan , lookup_breach.foreing_entry_valid,
        lookup_breach.foreing_entry_id, foreign_key.foreign_table::text, foreign_key.foreign_table::text= altered_table_name AS is_reference_ingoing
        FROM lookup_breach;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get this error when I call the function:

```
select * from ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach('country'::text, '{1}')
```

```
ERROR:  function aggregate_validity(country, bigint) does not exist
LINE 5:      aggregate_validity(country, airport.country_key) AS for...
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  CREATE TEMP TABLE lookup_breach ON COMMIT DROP AS
                       SELECT airport.entity_id AS source_entry_id, -- The Id of the source entry
                    airport.country_key AS foreing_entry_id, -- The id of the foreing entry
                    airport.valid AS source_entry_valid, -- the validity period of the source entry
                    aggregate_validity(country, airport.country_key) AS foreing_entry_valid, -- the validity period of the foreing entry
                    aggregate_validity(country, airport.country_key) <@ airport.valid as in_lifespan
                    FROM country, airport
                    WHERE airport.country_key = ANY($1)
                    AND airport.country_key = country_registration.entity_id
                    AND airport.registration @> now()::timestamp
                    GROUP BY airport.country_key, 
                    airport.entity_id,airport.valid,
                    country.valid
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach(text,bigint[]) line 33 at EXECUTE
```

Seems like I need some sort of casting? But I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Including the interactive "fiddle" is great, but could you [edit] the example into the question itself as well, in case the link breaks in future? Also make sure you've boiled it down to a [mcve] by removing all the details of the original task that aren't relevant to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I added the example.  and the example itself should be a MRE @IMSoP

Comment: I assume `c1olumn_attribute` is just a typo, meant to be `column_attribute`?

Answer (score 1):

You defined your custom function as `aggregate_validity(regclass, bigint)`.

A value of type `country` is not the same as type `regclass`. That's what the error message complains about:

> ```
> ERROR:  function aggregate_validity(country, bigint) does not exist
> LINE 5:      aggregate_validity(country, airport.country_key) AS for...
> ```

You might cast the string literal 'country' to `regclass` when passing to the aggregate function.

More importantly, you already use `format()`, so don't concatenate the SQL string manually, introducing a vector for **SQL injection**. Identifiers are not safe to concatenate literally and execute! See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

You also don't need to create a temporary table for every iteration of the loop.

And no separate `RETURN QUERY`. Merge that into a single instance of `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`.

Something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach(_altered_table_name text, _entity_ids bigint[])  
  RETURNS TABLE(source_entity                      text
              , source_entry_id                    bigint
              , source_entry_validity              tsrange
              , is_included_in_timeline            boolean
              , aggregated_foreign_entry_validity  tsrange
              , foreign_entry_id                   bigint
              , foreign_entity                     text
              , is_reference_ingoing               boolean)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   foreign_key record;
   is_reference_ingoing boolean;

BEGIN
   FOR foreign_key IN
      SELECT tc.table_name   AS source_table
           , kcu.column_name
           , ccu.table_name  AS foreign_table
      FROM   information_schema.table_constraints       tc 
      JOIN   information_schema.key_column_usage        kcu USING (constraint_name)
      JOIN   information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu USING (constraint_name)
      WHERE  tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
      AND    _altered_table_name IN (ccu.table_name, tc.table_name)
      AND    ccu.column_name <> 'row_id'
      AND    kcu.column_name <> 'entity_id'

   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
         'SELECT %1$L                                              -- AS source_entity
               , %1$I.entity_id                                    -- AS source_entry_id     -- the ID of the source entry
               , %1$I.valid                                        -- AS source_entry_valid, -- the validity period of the source entry
               , aggregate_validity(%3$L::regclass, %1$I.%2$I) <@ %1$I.valid -- AS in_lifespan
               , aggregate_validity(%3$L::regclass, %1$I.%2$I)               -- AS foreign_entry_valid -- the validity period of the foreign entry
               , %1$I.%2$I                                         -- AS foreign_entry_id    -- the ID of the foreign entry
               , $1                                                -- AS foreign_entity
               , $2                                                -- AS is_reference_ingoing
          FROM   %3$I, %1$I
          WHERE  %1$I.%2$I = ANY($3)
          AND    %1$I.%2$I = %3$I.entity_id  -- %3$I_registration.entity_id ???
          AND    %1$I.registration @> now()::timestamp
          GROUP  BY %1$I.entity_id
                  , %1$I.valid
                  , %1$I.%2$I
                  , %3$I.valid'  -- WHY this one ???
      , foreign_key.source_table    -- %1$I and %1$L
      , foreign_key.column_name     -- %2$I
      , foreign_key.foreign_table   -- %3$I and %3$L
      )
      USING foreign_key.foreign_table::text                        -- $1
          , foreign_key.foreign_table::text = _altered_table_name  -- $2
          , _entity_ids;                                           -- $3;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6803034bf6712dc36de32bb896fa9177)*

I fixed all instances of misspelled 'foreign'.

Note the explicit cast to `regclass`. It's not strictly needed as the correctly quoted sting literal (format specifier `L` in `%3$L`) would allow function resolution to kick in and cast to `regclass` automatically now. (You can try without the cast.)

About format specifiers in [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)

Might be simplified further, I didn't dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know what you are trying to do with above code. But you are getting the error because you are calling the function `ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach` with wrong parameter (as per your fiddle). You are providing the table name as `'coutry'`, but you should provide it as `'"country"'`.
So your `select` statement should be like below:

```
select * from ingoing_outgoing_reference_integrity_breach('"country"'::text, '{1}')
```

Comment: Nope, that's not one of the multiple problems.