# How to randomize data output in a View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How would one randomize data in a view?  The below code currently displays meals in the order they were entered into the DB.

e.g.

```
    <% @meals.each do |r| %>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
          <div class = "rest-box">
              <center><%= image_tag r.meal_photo.url(:medium) %></center>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view level you can use:

```
 <% @meals.shuffle.each do |r| %>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
      <div class = "rest-box">
          <center><%= image_tag r.meal_photo.url(:medium) %></center>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But it is preferred that you do it on your model in the controller.

```
@meals = Meal.order('RANDOM()')  # example
```

By the way, if you need it always you can make it your default scope like this in your model file:

```
default_scope -> {order(' RANDOM()' )}
```

So this will always return data randomly whenever you query for many results.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY random()
```

Or more sophisticated methods:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)