# escape character on copy csv

Tags: sql, shell, csv, copy, escaping

I have a sql script with intend to export data from postgres and spool into a csv file which used to work fine until I added random sample into the line.

Here is the code it look like with random()

```
\COPY (select accountid, to_char(createtime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ms') from accounts random()< 0.01 limit 1000) to '/home/oracle/scripts/accounts_p.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL AS ' '
```

ERROR MESSAGE when running this sql script:

```
psql:accounts_sample_p.sql:1: \copy: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...from accounts random ( ) < 0.01 l...

                              ^
```

Appearantly it did not like the `().` Tried using escape character with \ before ( and before ), but it did not help.

Can anyone give me an advice on how to overcome this?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be missing a 'WHERE' in your SELECT statement. i.e.:

```
select accountid, to_char(createtime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ms') from WHERE accounts random()< 0.01 limit 1000
```

Alternative methods on selecting a random set in PostgreSQL can be found here if you're struggling with performance:

[Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you!  What an embarrassing mistake!