# Update a certain amount of rows with a given attribute PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm writing a function in `PL/pgSQL` where I need to update a column in multiple rows. However, I need to update only 67 random rows of the larger number of rows.

For example, if I have a table of animals and I want to update the food column for each animal that is labeled `cat`, how can I update *ONLY 10* of those rows that are cats, and not update the other rows that are cats?

Comment: which 10 records you want to update `top 10` or `random 10`

Comment: I want to update a random 10 records

Comment: Does your table have any ID Column ? If possible show sample table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql) on how to select n random rows.  Use it as follows.

Step 1 - create a temporary table.

Step 2 - insert your random rows into this table.  Use the reference to see how to do it.

Step 3 - update the records in the temporary table

Step 4 - update the real table from the temporary table

Step 5 - drop the temporary table.