# Fastest query for random row from subset of large table - postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using rails and Postgresql.  I have a very large table that includes a column called status.  From this status column a lot of rows have a value of 1.  I want to select a random row based on all rows with a value of 1 in the status column.  Each row also has an id and they are sequential.

What is the fastest way to get this random row?

Comment: I would recommend also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql for good discussion on how to perform this query effectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **ActiveRecord** solution, e.g :

```
Model_name.where(status: 1).limit(1).order("RANDOM()")
```

OR :

```
Model_name.where(status: 1).order("RANDOM()").first
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is the limit 5 if I only need 1 row? Is that a typo?

Comment: You can use `.first`.

Comment: So its just making the order of the subset random and picking the first one?  It doesn't need to go through all the records right?

Comment: How would I change the second line to pick a subset where status = 1 AND a second column lets say apples does not equal 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `OFFSET` option

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 OFFSET random()*I LIMIT 1;`

The I is the number of rows in table.

Comment: What is the number of rows in the table is constantly changing?

Comment: You probably mean `LIMIT 1`

Comment: You can write `offset random() * (select count(*) from users)`