# SQL - Returning random rows from a temporary table using NEWID()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, newid

I am trying to insert data from a source table in to a temporary table using the `NEWID()` function so that I get a (fairly) random selection of lines from my source table.

Looking at the below code, I insert the data I need into the temp table `#x` and at *Point 1* where I select from `#x`, it returns the data in a random order.

However, at *Point 2* WHERE I am narrowing down the data from `#x` (I accumulate lines until a certain quantity is reached) the SELECT no longer returns random rows - it returns rows in a sequential order from the start of the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x
CREATE TABLE #x (Id INT, Commodity VARCHAR(3), Quantity FLOAT, RowNum INT, TotalQuantity FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #x (id,commodity,quantity,rownum,totalquantity)
  SELECT
    i.id, i.commodity, i.quantity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.id), SUM(i.quantity) OVER (ORDER BY i.id RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  FROM inventory i
  WHERE .........
        .........
  ORDER BY NEWID()


SELECT * FROM #x   -------- **POINT 1**


DECLARE @y INT = (SELECT MIN(rownum) AS minrownum FROM #x WHERE totalquantity >= @tonnes)


SELECT #x.id, #x.commodity, #x.quantity, #x.rownum, #x.totalquantity FROM #x
WHERE #x.rownum <= @y
ORDER BY NEWID()         -------- **POINT 2**
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your query and question are confusing.  Part of the question seems to want a random set of rows.  However, the code is generating the first N rows that add to a particular value.

Comment: I'm a bit confused myself Gordon. What I am trying to do is select random lines from a table until a certain cumulative quantity is reached.

Comment: FYI, Postgres 9.5 gained the [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) command to nearly-randomly pull a sample subset of the rows. Discussed at end of [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8675160/642706) to similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL.   Your row number is deterministic.  There may be better ways to do what you want, but you can fix the above code by randomizing the *row number*:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY newid())
```

The outer `ORDER BY` is probably unnecessary.

Your query, though is quite confusing.  It is selecting the first N rows (by id) that sum up to the total quantity.  This makes a lot of sense.  I'm not sure what all the randomization is for.

EDIT:

If you need to get random rows until a certain number is reached, you can do:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*, SUM(i.quantity) OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) as cume_quantity
      FROM inventory i
      WHERE .........
            .........
     ) i
WHERE cume_quantity - quantity < @tonnes;
```

You don't need a temporary table.  You don't need additional queries.

Comment: It needs to select random rows unfortunately. The IDs relate to inventory and I can't give out the same numbers each time the query is executed.