# Select Random from Postgresql Table with Where clauses and without PK

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having a table from which I want to select N random rows in PostgreSQL.

However, I don't want to select the whole table, but I want to select random from the rows that respect some constraints (e.g. Price in range, Color = "red" etc.)

I have already seen some ways to do this when id's are generated in a continuous manner. However, in this case, there will be a lot of gaps.

Is there any way of doing this without using order by random() which is to expensive?

Comment: you can use ctid instead of sequential key, but it will probably take same time as `order by random()`

Answer (score 1):

With postgresql 9.5 you can use

> TABLESAMPLE with methods BERNOULLI and SYSTEM

Hier is some good examples and explanations which is better:

[How to select random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/41337788#41337788)

[Compare different random methods](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-and-other-methods-for-getting-random-tuples/)

[More examples here](https://www.depesz.com/2015/05/23/waiting-for-9-5-tablesample-sql-standard-and-extensible/)

First install the extension:

> CREATE EXTENSION tsm_system_rows;

Try with this:

```
Select * from your_table tablesample   system_rows(1000)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm gonna look into it and try to understand how it works better tomorrow. It might solve my problems.

Comment: It works pretty good, but gets me grouped random elements, so if N is a random number I also get N+1, N+2. I think it's linked with pagination. It's faster, though.

Comment: @silidragos I know this is years later but the SYSTEM method will return random pages of data, so they'll be grouped together, whereas the slower BERNOULLI method will return random rows