# PostgreSQL - Random order with Distinct on

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, reverse

I am trying to return products in random order (or descending order) and have a button that gets more random products that are NOT part of previous random products. Basically if I have 15 products total, I want 3 random products, and then click button and get 3 more random items and so on until there are no more items.

I have a pretty whack query going on to get data from my tables.

I'm using the '**DISTINCT on**' to get one product and show it's lowest price (without it, it will list the product for however many prices it has). I know that it is effecting the random ordering / descending ordering.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT on (products.id) products.*, prices.price FROM products
INNER JOIN product_price_size ON products.id = product_price_size.productId
INNER JOIN prices ON prices.id = product_price_size.priceId
WHERE active = true AND (archived IS NULL OR archived = false)
ORDER BY products.id, prices.price LIMIT 3
```

The 'get more products' button is basically the same query with **OFFSET** being a variable after **LIMIT 3**

Hopefully this makes sense. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve what I'm trying to get?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql) contains valuable information for you.

Comment: `OFFSET` should not be affecting the descending ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Correct, it's not. But it's also not returning random rows from the total rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep incrementing the offset of a stable ordering. One ordering might be based on a deterministic hash like `md5` (change `some_random_salt` for a new ordering):

```
select id from tbl
order by md5(id || 'some_random_salt'), id
limit 3 offset ?
```

Or the modulo of prime number (change the prime number for a different ordering):

```
select id from tbl
order by id % 11, id
limit 3 offset ?
```

Then increment the offset:

```
[...]
limit 3 offset 3

[...]
limit 3 offset 6
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. But I'm looking to get them in a random order.