# Fetch random records from Ecto database

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Is it possible to fetch 10 random records from database using only pure Ecto queries, and not on application side? For example, I'm don't want to get all records from the database and then take random values from them in Elixir (like this):

```
Subscribers
|> Repo.all
|> Enum.take_random(10)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ecto doesn't provide a generic `random` function for retrieving records, because the underlying databases/schemas can (*and do*) implement it in very different ways.

But if you know what database you're dealing with, you can use [`fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) and [`limit/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#limit/3) to achieve that. For [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), **you can use them with the [`RANDOM()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql) function:**

```ex
import Ecto.Query

query =
  from Subscribers,
  order_by: fragment("RANDOM()"),
  limit: 10

Repo.all(query)
```

---

This is equivalent to calling this `sql` query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM subscribers ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: (Remember to call `import Ecto.Query` first)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question trying to figure out how to grab a single random record that has a nil parent_task property.

thought I'd post my solution incase it helps anyone.

### solution 1

if someone knows how to avoid doing List.first and only use Ecto queries I'd appreciate a comment!

```
    query =
      from t in Subscriber,
      where: is_nil(t.parent_task),
      order_by: fragment("RANDOM()"),
      limit: 1

    Repo.all(query) |> List.first
```

### solution 2

```
Repo.all(Subscriber) |> Enum.filter(fn x -> is_nil(x.parent_task) end) |> Enum.random()
```

Comment: Instead of `Repo.all(query) |> List.first()`, you can use `Repo.one(query)` or `Repo.one!(query)`