# how to get random entry from db?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I need to get a random record from the database. How i do it:

```php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
$totalRowsTable = $qb->select('count(article.id)')->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
var_dump($totalRowsTable);

$random = (int)max(0, rand(1, $totalRowsTable));
var_dump($random);

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
     ->andWhere("article.id IN (:id)")
     ->setParameter('id', $random)
     ->setMaxResult(1);
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I'm not understanding why the function returns zero. How can I get a random record from the database in a more correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

Comment: The number of entries does not necessarily match the IDs of your data rows. i.e. your row Ids could start at 10000 but you only have 50 entries. You'd never get a result then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$idArticle = $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
            ->select('MIN(article.id)', 'MAX(article.id)')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
        $random = rand($idArticle[1], $idArticle[2]);

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
            ->where('article.id >= :randomId')
            ->setParameter('randomId', $random)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that could be correct answer for your questions.

First off all we have to calculate number of rows in table by executing followed code:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
$count = $queryBuilder
    ->select('COUNT(article.id)')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Next, we have to calculate random value from 0 to `$count`.
But functions [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) or even [mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) are not enought secured to use becouse of:

> Caution
> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

Insted of that we should use for example function [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php).
So, to choose secured random values we implements code below:

```
$offset = random_int(0, max(0, $count - 1));
```

And at least, we could retrive random row record for table:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResult(1)
    ->getOneOrNullResult;
```