# PostgreSQL. Select a column that correlates with value in the aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, greatest-n-per-group

Here is the 'items' table, containing more than 10 rows:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id  | item_name | category  | quantity |
+=====+===========+===========+==========+
| 3   | item33    | category1 | 5        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 2   | item52    | category5 | 1        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1   | item46    | category1 | 3        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 4   | item11    | category3 | 2        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| ... | ...       | ...       | ...      |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Values in the 'items' column are unique, the ones in the 'category' columnt - aren't unique.

The task is:

1. Remove duplicates of categories: if a category contains more than 1 item, take the row with minimal 'id'.
2. Order results by the 'quantity' (ASC).
3. Take 10 rows: top 5 and random 5 from the rest result data output.

So, the ordering table (after #2 sub-task) should look like that:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id  | item_name | category  | quantity |
+=====+===========+===========+==========+
| 2   | item52    | category5 | 1        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 4   | item11    | category3 | 2        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1   | item46    | category1 | 3        |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| ... | ...       | ...       | ...      |
+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I know how to exclude duplicates for categories:

```
SELECT min(id) as id, category
FROM items
GROUP BY category
```

But I don't know how to order it by the quantity.
If I try to add 'quantity' to the 'select' line and then make 'ORDER BY quantity', I get the error: *"column "quantity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"*.

If there is a way to add this 'quantity' column to the data output (the value in this column should correlate with the resulting 'id' value (i.e. "min(id)"))? And then do ordering and picking rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider joining back your aggregate query to the unit level data for all columns including `quantity`:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.item_name, i.category, i.quantity
FROM items i
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT category, min(id) AS min_id
   FROM items
   GROUP BY category) agg
 ON i.id = agg.min_id
 AND i.category = agg.category
ORDER BY i.quantity
```

For top 5 and random 5 split, integrate a union with CTE to hold the resultset:

```sql
WITH sub AS (
  SELECT i.id, i.item_name, i.category, i.quantity
  FROM items i
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT category, min(id) AS min_id
     FROM items
     GROUP BY category) agg
   ON i.id = agg.min_id
   AND i.category = agg.category
)

-- TOP 5 ROWS
SELECT id, item_name, category, quantity
FROM sub
ORDER BY i.quantity
LIMIT 5

UNION

-- RANDOM ROWS OF NON-TOP 5
SELECT id, item_name, category, quantity
FROM 
  (SELECT id, item_name, category, quantity
   FROM sub
   ORDER BY i.quantity
   OFFSET 5) below5
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This solution works best for me, 'cause with my little knowledge of Postgres I can at least understand this code :D
Thanks for the help everyone, regardless. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! This solution also works in other RDBMS's and not limited to Postgres dialect methods. Happy SQLing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (order by quantity) as rn_q
 from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by category order by id) as rn
  From your_table) t
Where rn = 1) t
Order by case when rn_q <= 5 then quantity else 6 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `DISTINCT ON` serves nicely in Postgres. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by/9796104#9796104)

Simple (correct!) solution:

```sql
WITH dist_cat AS (
   SELECT t, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY quantity, id) AS rn   -- added id as tiebreaker
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (category) *
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY category, id
      ) t  -- distinct categories
   ORDER  BY ORDER BY quantity, id  -- match sort for row_number()
   )
SELECT (t).*
FROM   dist_cat
WHERE  rn <= 5

UNION ALL   -- not just UNION
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT (t).*
FROM   dist_cat
WHERE  rn > 5
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  5
);
```

Added `id` as tiebreaker to the sort, as sorting by `quantity` is hardly deterministic. Put any unique expression there that suits your requirements. Or skip it if you are OK with arbitrary results that may change with every call.

The row type `t` is for convenience, so we don't have to spell out all column names, and still get rid of the appended `rn` in the result, which has not been requested.

I chose to order rows in the CTE and attach a row nubmer `rn` to avoid an additional sort operation.

The additional 5 random rows are *truly* picked randomly, not just arbitrarily.

Use `UNION ALL`, not just `UNION`. Because it's *correct* for what we are doing, and cheaper, too. But also to preserve the the sort order from the CTE; `UNION` can mess it up trying to remove duplicates - in vain.

For big tables, depending on data distribution, there may be (much) faster techniques ...

... for getting unique categories:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

.. for getting random rows:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)