# best way to select a single random row from table

Tags: postgresql

I tried the approach suggested here: [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_test_user() RETURNS JSONB AS $$
  WITH j_ret AS (
    SELECT * FROM "User"
    WHERE "nickname" LIKE 'test%' AND random() < 0.2 LIMIT 1
  )
  SELECT to_jsonb(j_ret) FROM j_ret;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

However, when the table is small, it occasionally returns null. What's the best way to return just 1 random single row?

Comment: What is best depends on what compromises you are willing to make for the sake of performance.  S-mans answer will not be fast, but it is pretty much foolproof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is independent from the table size:

```
SELECT * FROM "User"
WHERE "nickname" LIKE 'test%'
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```