# How to sample a PostgreSQL database using Prisma?

Tags: postgresql, sampling, prisma

Suppose I have several millions of statements in my PostgreSQL database and I want to get only 10000 of them. But not the first 10000, rather, a random selection of 10000 (it would be best if I could also choose the logic, e.g. select every 4th statement).

How could I do this using Prisma, or — if it's not possible using Prisma — using a good old PostgreSQL request?

For now, I'm using this code to limit the number of results I'm getting:

```js
const statements = await this.prisma.statement.findMany({
      where: {
        OR: conditions,
      },
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'asc',
      },
      take: 10000,
    });
```

This will use the conditions I have, then order them in ascending order, and "take" or limit the first 10000 results.

What could I use in place of the "take" or what request I could make directly in PostgreSQL to randomly sample my DB for records?

Comment: Please have a look at `[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)` post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma doesn't natively support fetching random data as of now.

There is a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5894) that discusses the exact same scenario as you need.

The alternative could be to use [queryRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) for raw database access and use PostgreSQL's [random](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-math.html) function as described in the above mentioned Feature Request.

Comment: Thank you, @Nurul. Could you please tell me how I use the `random` function to retrieve the random 10000 from all the available records? This was not clear to me from the comment above. Thanks!