# Generate random pairs SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Suppose we have these two tables.

TABLE1:

```
|column_1 |    ...  |
--------------------
|   'a'   |    ...  |  
|   'b'   |    ...  |  
|   'c'   |    ...  |   
|   'd'   |    ...  |   
|   'e'   |    ...  |
```

TABLE_2:

```
|column_1 |    ...  |
--------------------
|   1     |    ...  |  
|   2     |    ...  |  
|   3     |    ...  |   
|   4     |    ...  |   
|   5     |    ...  |
```

I want to pair all rows of TABLE_1 with some random columns from TABLE_2 where each pair is gonna have a random amount of distinct rows from TABLE_2 (range 1,2,3)

An output could be:

```
|column_1 |    column_2  |
---------------------------
|   'a'   |    1         | 
|   'a'   |    2         | 
|   'a'   |    5         | 
|   'b'   |    5         | 
|   'c'   |    3         | 
|   'c'   |    4         | 
|   'd'   |    3         | 
|   'e'   |    3         | 
|   'e'   |    5         | 
|   'e'   |    1         |
```

Comment: what did you try to solve this yourself? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service!

Comment: see: [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

Comment: I have tried adding a new column on a cte based on table_1 with the amount of selections I will get from table_2. I will select randomly from table_2 with that limit, but I don't know how to do it in a single query for all rows of table1. @Luuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOIN LATERAL
```

did the thing for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 LIMIT FLOOR(RANDOM() * 3 + 1)) a
    ON TRUE
```