# How to generate random data for association table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, random, data-generation

I am working on an e-shop with three tables: `products`, `atributes` and `product_atributes`. I have already filled tables `products` and `atributes`:

```
insert into atribute(name)
select random_atribute()
from generate_series(1,10000) as seq(i);

insert into product(price)
select floor(1 + random() * 100)::int
from generate_series(1,20000) as seq(i);
```

I want to generate **random data** for the table `product_atributes`: There can be 1 attribute for 1 product but also all attributes for just 1 product. The result should look like:

```
product_atributes
id  product_id     atribute_id
1      5               12
2      5               76
3      5               10
4      5                7
5      1               45
6      1               109
...
```

Table `product_atributes` is created like this:

```
create table product_atributes(
  id serial primary key,
  atribute_id integer references atribute(id),
  product_id integer references product(id)
);
```

I tried sth. like this, but it's not working:

```
with data as (
    select  s.i,
            random_atribute_id() as atribute_id,
            s.id as product_id
   
    from (generate_series(1, 1000) as seq(i)
             cross join lateral (select seq.i, * from product order by random() limit 1) as s)
)

insert into product_atributes(atribute_id, product_id)
select atribute_id, product_id from data;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple

To insert every possible combination with an even chance of 1 percent:

```sql
INSERT INTO product_atributes(product_id, atribut_id)
SELECT p.product_id, a.atribut_id
FROM   product p
JOIN   atribute a ON random() >= 0.99;
```

#### More sophisitcated & faster

This offers more control over minimum and maximum number of attributes.

And it's **a lot faster** for your particular setup with **gap-less** attribute IDs (from 1 to 10000):

```sql
INSERT INTO product_atributes(product_id, atribut_id)
SELECT p.product_id, a.atribut_id
FROM  (SELECT product_id, trunc(random() * 10)::int AS ct FROM product) p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT DISTINCT 1 + trunc(random() * 10000) AS atribut_id
   FROM   generate_series (0, p.ct) g
   ) a;
```

This generates 0 to 10 completely random associations per product.
`2 + trunc(random() * 6)::int AS ct` would generate 3 to 8 associations. (Note the 0-based `generate_series()`!)

Generate the number of attributes (`ct`) in a subquery to avoid single evaluation of `random()` resulting in the same number for all products.

We can optimize performance for gap-less IDs quite a bit. Instead of  walking through all 10000 attribute for every product, just generate random numbers for the given range of IDs. *Much* faster.
Throw in `DISTINCT` to eliminate (unlikely) duplicates. Hardly matters for 10 our of 10000, but we can't allow duplicates. (So it's *possible* to get fewer associations in rare cases.)

We could even work with a few gaps. There are quite a few subtleties to selecting random rows. See:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)

#### Asides

You could also populate all three tables with random data in a single query using  [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Simple example for a 1:n relationship:

- [How can I generate fake data that adheres to the PRIMARY KEY-FOREIGN KEY constraints of my schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244165/3684)

Same principle for your case, jut two CTEs ...

Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

"Attributes" are spelled like this.