# Postgresql: Is it possible to define dynamic where conditions based on the result set size?

Tags: postgresql

My problem is the following:
I have a query that searches for all the products containing an input string, and from that result set I am picking 10 random entries. The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE text &@* 'salt' AND random() < 0.01 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

This works flawlessly as long as the result set is big. But if the search for the string returns a handful of rows (in the range of 10 or below), chances are that I will get nothing back. So for a result set size <= 10 a value of `random() < 1` will work better, but this won't work properly for big sets as I will start getting the same thing all the time. Implementing this logic at the middleware level can be done but obviously with performance penalties.

So my question is, is there a way to define this condition dynamically at the SQL level, based on the first select result set size?

My PostgreSQL version is : PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

PS: I want to stick with `random() < #` approach to get random values as it is the fastest approach I was able to test so far. And speed is very important in my case.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM products WHERE text &@* 'salt' order by random() LIMIT 10 ;`?

Comment: Yes but this approach is slower than AND random() < #

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

Comment: Yes, `order by random()` will be slower, how much depends on data volumn. But it always gives the correct answer even with small data volumes, which not doing so is your issue. *A slower query which gives the correct result is always preferred to an extremely fast one that gives incorrect results.*