# SQL select: random order values from one table for each row in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have two tables in my database:

**(1) PHRASES:**

```
t_phrase
========
I like
They prefer
...
Somebody else wants
```

and

**(2) PLACES:**

```
n_id   t_place
====   =======
1      London
2      Paris
...
N      New York
```

Table `PHRASES` has at least as many rows as `PLACES`.  I need to join these two tables in such a way as to select all `place`s with one `phrase` for each of them - but phrases need to be randomly distributed across places.  The overall `places` table isn't too big: maybe, about 3-4 thousand rows, however there will be an additional `WHERE` clause on it that will limit the output to about 200 places at most.

Ideally, I'd like this to be in one SQL statement, but so far I haven't been able to get my head around this.  Therefore the second option is a stored function returning a row of `(int, varchar, varchar)`.  For this, I was thinking of something along the lines of:

1. select all phrases in random order into an array of varchar
2. loop over places taking one at a time and returning it along with the next phrase from the array

Somehow this seems to me very inefficient, but I can't come up with anything better.

Can you suggest any better idea?  Or, even better, one statement SQL, maybe?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Please note that the phrases should NOT be repeated in the resultset.  There are always at least as many phrases as there are places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will work:

```
select (select phrase from phrases order by random() limit 1),
       place
from places
```

The select within the select should be called for each row, so it should return a different value each time.

If you want just a random arrangement of the phrases and places, you can use windows functions:

```
select ph.phrase, p.place
from (select place, row_number() over (order by place) as seqnum
      from places p
     ) p join
     (select phrase, row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
      from phrases
     ) ph 
     on p.seqnum = ph.seqnum
```

This orders the places by place (or any field could do).  It randomizes the phrases, and joins on the resulting row numbers.

Comment: This won't work, as it will select random each time resulting potentially in repeated phrases.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I thought you wanted a random phrase for each place.  I will revise the solution for this case.

Comment: What's the performance implications of the first example?  I'd be concerned that, despite the `LIMIT 1`, it's still going to run over the entire table for every `place` (granted, not a large result set here, but...)

Comment: If you are interested in the performance implications, check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres.  There is no a priori reason why postgres should read the table each time, but that is up to the database implementors.

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly, even on our antiquated 8.3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH p AS (
    SELECT place, row_number() OVER () AS rn
    FROM   t_place
    WHERE  <some condition>
    )
    , ph AS (
    SELECT phrase, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM   t_phrase
    )
SELECT ph.phrase, p.place
FROM   p
JOIN   ph USING (rn);
```

It won't get any more random, if you impose a truly random order on both tables, it will only get slower. I impose the random order on phrases, because:

> There are always at least as many phrases as there are places.

It needs to be done with the bigger set, lest some non-random part might get cut off. For the smaller set (places), on the other hand, *any* sequence of numbers without gaps is good, so I pick the fastest way.

My example uses CTEs, but it can be done with subqueries just as well. Both [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) and [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) require PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.

Comment: Yep, this works.  Unfortunately, live db is 8.3, so I'd have to use sub-queries.  Thanks.