# Understanding random ordering in Rails + postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'd like to do some random ordering when displaying data the code I have at this point is:

```
Timsheet.limit(1).offset(RANDOM(Timesheet.count)).first
```

I know that postgresql's (RANDOM) syntax is different than MYSQL's (RAND()) and Oracles (dbms_random.value) syntax.

I'd just like to confirm that my code is correct, from what I understand it's doing is, it's grabbing the first row, and offsetting the data in a random order?

Please help clear this up, thanks!

Comment: I think you want `Timsheet.order('RANDOM()').first`: This will make a random order and select the first record: *in fine* you get one random record. --- Using your code (with offset) always returns the same record in my IRB console

Comment: You should be able to see, in your log, what sql is generated from your ruby code: that's always a good sanity check.   Looking at it, i would say that it will grab a random timesheet record from the table.

Comment: Actually maybe not.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work with all  DBMS's

```
Timsheet.offset(Random.new.rand(Timsheet.count)).first
```