# Rails - Query n random records from an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two classes. `User` and `Review` (User has many reviews).

I am trying to find then best method to extract two random reviews from the association of `User.reviews`

I can use `user.reviews.order("RANDOM()").limit(n)` but if I'm not mistaken this will be very heavy on the DB if I have users with a large number of reviews...

I am using Postgres as my database.

Thoughts?

Comment: What DB you are using ?

Comment: I am using Postgres. Added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is.. Ok.. as DB native method will take care of it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [quick random row selection in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres)

Answer (score 2):

A database independent solution would be:

```
user.reviews.where(id: user.reviews.pluck(:id).sample(2))
```

I always prefer database independent solutions because otherwise it doesn't make sense to use ActiveRecord at all. Obviously this solution does two DB requests compared to your `RANDOM()` approach. Performance wise it is a tricky question because the database can cache these requests. It can not cache a `RANDOM()` request.