# Postgres group by and then show one random from that group

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of records each of which belongs to a collection.
I want to list the collections and with each collection have a random record from that collection.

Currently I have a count but I would like to also return the random id from the records table. I cannot get my head around it. Any suggestions?

Current query.

```
 select
   collections.name,collections.id, count(records.id) as count
 from
   collections, records
 where
   records.collection_id = collections.id
 group by
   collections.id
 order by
   collections.name
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate as the link doesn't include a join that I can see.

Comment: following the above question, yours should be something like     select collections.id AS random.id from collections, records 
        where records.collection_id = collections.id group by collections.id 
        OFFSET floor(random()* (select count(*) from collections, records 
        where records.collection_id = collections.id group by collections.id ))
         LIMIT 1;

Comment: `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Comment: remove group by "select collections.id AS random.id from collections, records where records.collection_id = collections.id  OFFSET floor(random()* (select count(*) from collections, records where records.collection_id = collections.id )) LIMIT 1;"

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer, from the comments above

```
select collections.id AS random.id from collections, records 
 where records.collection_id = collections.id 
  OFFSET floor(random()* (select count(*) from collections, records 
                          where records.collection_id = collections.id ))
  LIMIT 1;
```