# How can I shuffle a result I get from a Postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm using psycopg2 in a python script:

```
  conn = psycopg2.connect(......)
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("select * from table1")
  rows = cur.fetchall()
  for a1 in rows: # how to shuffle them?
```

I want the rows to be in a different order each time I retrieve them. How can I do that?

**update**:

the amount of rows is around 50.000

Comment: How about doing this server side?

Comment: How many rows do you select from table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the count is not huge, you could use `random.shuffle`:

```
from random import shuffle

...

rows = list(cur.fetchall())
shuffle(rows)
# do what you need with the suffled rows
```

Otherwise you could select items in a random order. There're ways to do it in Postgres:

1) [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

2) [quick random row selection in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres)

Comment: it's around 50k rows in my case. is it huge?

Comment: I think yes, it would consume a lot of memory. I would recommend you to select your items in a random order instead of shuffling in Python. In order to do it see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres

Comment: where is shuffing in these links? they merely are selecting random elements, not all elements in a random order.

Comment: `select * from table1 order by random()`