# Rails—get a random record from db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

To get a single random record from the db, I'm currently doing:

`User.all.sample`

But when there are 100000+ users, it takes a few seconds to load them all, just to select one.

What's the simplest way to get load a single random user from db?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try following database independent query:

```
User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample)
[DEBUG]  (36.5ms)  SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users`
[DEBUG] User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 58229 LIMIT 1
```

this one fires two queries but this one is performance efficient as it took only **37ms** to get single random user record.

whereas the following query will take around **624.7ms**

```
User.order("RAND()").first
[DEBUG] User Load (624.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

I have checked this for 105510 user records.

Comment: `User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample)` is great, not DB-type dependent. If anyone needs more than one record, you can add an argument to sample, like `User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample(4))`

Comment: I don't recommend any of this. The first solution will consume more and more memory depending on users count. The second solution can be really slow and also consume significant resources. There many alternatives depending on what kind of random you **really** need. Actually I recommend to avoid randomization as much as possible.

Comment: what are other efficient  alternatives. please post them as answer so others will also came to know the solution.

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov  I need a random record from the db, no special kind of random, just a random record. If you have a more efficient solution please share

Comment: @GaneshNavale You will load array with all ids to memory. Imagine you have thousands of hundreds ids.

Comment: @Mirror318 This is one of them https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297523/3702804

Comment: @AlexTatarnikov Offset is mentioned in another comment, you should post it as an answer here

Comment: offset mention in another comment will be less efficient, and will take approx **565 ms**

Comment: `User.offset(rand(User.count)).limit(1).take`

How does this work for you guys? For me, it took less than 10ms whereas others were taking around 80ms.

Comment: Check the first solution on a table containing 25m of records (well, I did, this does not work). The second one works but it takes some time. Fully agree with @AlexTatarnikov

Answer (score 15):

Using **Postgresql** or **SQLite**, using `RANDOM()`:

```
User.order("RANDOM()").take
```

Presumably the same would work for **MySQL** with `RAND()`

```
User.order("RAND()").take
```

Comment: that's great, is there anything that doesn't change with db types?

Comment: @fongfan999 that only works if you don't have any holes (deleted records).

Comment: This is the best answer imo. I think Rails should implement it's own random record function in Active Record to hide this though.

Comment: @fongfan999 at first dont do User.count on big tables and then it wont work if your table have gaps, as it was already mentioned

Comment: More generic `Model.first(offset: rand(Model.count))` does a better job.

Comment: better use `#take` instead of `#first` for efficiency

Comment: From Rails 6.1, this won't run any more. Use `.order(Arel.sql('RAND()'))` instead (passing literals to `.order` is deemed unsafe and has been deprecated for quite some time now.)

Answer (score 9):

Well after lot of trials and errors i've found this solution to be helpful and error free.

```
Model.find(Model.ids.sample)
```

`Model.ids` will return an array of all ids in the database. we then call `sample` method on that array that will return a random item in the list.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the maximum user id in the table and find a user given a random id limited to this maximum. Example:

```
max_id = User.order(id: :desc).limit(1).pluck(:id).first
user = User.find_by('id > ?', rand(max_id))
```

These two queries are extremely fast because you are using the index for the primary key (id).

Comment: It seems too me you dont need pluck there

Comment: This solution is the fastest one, and obviously underestimated at the moment of this comment

Comment: This solution does not hold up in you use UUID/GUID for your id type because `rand()` accepts an integer

Answer (score 3):

for rails 6

you can pass records count to get how many records you want

`User.all.sample(1)`

Above Query will Return only one random record of the user

Comment: This code will make this request to database: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users"` - fetching all users into memory.

Comment: This example has nothing to do with Rails 6, and the question explains the problem with this and is looking for a more efficient alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to run some simple benchmarks, using PostgreSQL, Rails 7 and a table with 65k records.
In my case I needed a random record after a scope.

**TL;DR in order from best to worst**

```rb
1) Model.scope.order('RANDOM()').first 
2) Model.find(Model.scope.ids.sample)
3) Model.scope.sample
```

For a more detailed answer here's the snippet I ran

```rb
require 'benchmark'

N = 1000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('sample') { N.times { Model.scope.sample } }
  x.report('find ids sample') { N.times { Model.find(Model.scope.ids.sample) } }
  x.report('RANDOM()') { N.times { Model.scope.order('RANDOM()').first } }
end
```

And the results were

```bash
                | user        system    total      real
sample          | 957.387427  11.710236 969.097663 (1054.653218)
find ids sample | 64.859209   3.164221  68.023430  (97.080131)
RANDOM()        | 0.819056    0.086088  0.905144   (11.837224)
```

Comment: Your number 1) gets me (Rails 5.2, mysql) a severe rap on the knuckles: *DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "RAND()". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().*

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Scroll to the bottom of the answer - strategy #5 is what I use today.

---

I've actually implemented this in an app, where I randomly need to pull a record out of a growing list of currently 1_000_000 records (for business reasons).

1. Use DB `RANDOM` for PostgreSQL/SQLite or `RAND` for MySQL/MariaDB

   - Pro: Most robust
   - Con: Slow. As the table grows, takes longer and longer (~260ms on my table)

     ```rb
       User.order('RANDOM()').limit(1)
     ```
2. Pluck/Select IDs and then use Ruby Array#sample to get a random id. Then look up that record in DB

   - Pro: faster (~50ms on my table)
   - Con: As your tables grows you it will start getting slower, and you simply may run out of resources, depending on the size of the machine. i.e.: you're running on a small VM

     ```rb
       User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample)
     ```
3. Get min & man value of IDs in the DB, then `rand(min..max)` and do a find_by (in case you hit a deleted record) in DB for that record:

   - Pro

     - Extremely fast, if no deleted data (~17ms on my sample data)
     - If the table grows, it doesn't affect the speed of the lookup
   - Con

     - Requires Numeric IDs, can't use GUID or Varchar IDs
     - Needs sequential IDs without missing IDs
     - Can be brittle if any records were deleted and ID's are missing.

       - Error handling & additional lookups can mitigate the problem, but as number of missing IDs becomes larger, this will slow as well

   ```rb
   User.find_by(rand(1..User.count))
   ```
4. There is another strategy that I haven't seen other answers mention - Random Offset. Just make sure it's in the range of your existing records.

- Pro: no error handling needed, doesn't depend on the type of ID
- Con: Not as fast - about 120ms on avg on my sample data, but depending on where the offset is in the table the actual queries can be anywhere between 20ms and 600ms. That's just how offset works.

  ```rb
  User.offset(rand(1..User.count)).limit(1)
  ```

Ultimately, I chose 3rd strategy - despite the cons, it is still faster **on average** for my use-case. Our deletes from that table are also rare, and we use soft deletes, that I can use in my error handling. However, since I came up with Strategy #4 - I've been using that sometimes. Works well.

**Tips:**

- If the actual current count is not critical: You can preload User.count and memorize it as User.total_count (for example) or keep in an app-load config, that gets loaded on app restart, and you can either invalidate this caches or restart your app on a regular basis.  This will remove the extra 15-20ms needed to get User.count and will speed up option 3 to under 3ms, and option 4 to about 100ms

  ```rb
  def self.total_count
    @total_count ||= count
  end
  ```

  This is another reason I used stratagem #3. Even hitting "missing" records, and having to error handle it and do additional lookups, until I find a "working" random records - is very cheap. In the time I can look up using other strategies, I can do 5-10 look-ups using this approach and still be ahead of the curve on speed.
- Error handling can be done 2 ways:

  - Do lookups until you find one that exists
  - Do 3 (5, 10) lookups, and then select a random one from the result set. Still superfast (especially if you memoize User.count as User.total_count or just do User.count, before executing this statement below). In Rails `find_by` will return result or nil
  - ***Depending on your data User.maximum(:id) and User.count, maybe the same or close enough to not matter, but they can be also widely apart. So be careful.*** Do User.maximum(:id) or User.last.id, instead of User.count if you have a lot of gaps in your data. In my case, there are no gaps - so the result is the same.

  ```rb
  max = User.maximum(:id)
  ids = 5.times.map { rand(1..max) }
  User.where(id: ids).sample
  ```

Error handling should be chosen, depending on how many "missing" records you have in a sequence.  If you have a lot, then strategy #3 may not be a good choice.

**EDIT - new strategy #5:**

Adding 5th strategy. I've come up with after finishing this post, and  I think this is the fastest, while being the most robust

5. Get min & man value of IDs in the DB, then `rand(min..max)`and do a where lookup:

   - Pro

     - Extremely fast - I get 1-6ms results
     - If the table grows, it doesn't affect the speed of the lookup (actually faster than offset)
     - If records get deleted, it will just find the first match after the deleted one.
     - Can be modified into a scope, and used with other scopes - i.e `User.published_today.random_record` (Just keep in mind that it's essentially reimplementing an offset in a way, which may limit your data set for a lookup)
   - Con

     - Not as clear as using just `offset`, but offset will get slow er depending on how big is your data.

   ```rb
   # `random_id` Can be memoized / cached, but beware of scoping before caching!!!
   random_id = rand(User.minumum(:id)..User.maximum(:id)) 
   User.where("id >= ?", random_id).limit(1)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> User.offset(0..(rand(User.count))).limit(1).sample

Enjoy it :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can get a sample in Rails console using `Model.all.sample.attribute`.

E.g.:

```
Contact.all.sample.name
=> "Bob Mcmillan"
```

Comment: This answer loads the entire table into memory and is extremely inefficient.