# postgresql: How to grab an existing id from a not subsequent ids of a table

Tags: postgresql, random, row-number, floor

*Postgresql version 9.4*

I have a table with an integer column, which has a number of integers with some gaps, like the sample below; I'm trying to get an existing id from the column at random with the following query, but it returns NULL occasionally:

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS test_tbl(
    id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO test_tbl
VALUES (10),
       (13),
       (14),
       (16),
       (18),
       (20);
-------------------------------    
SELECT * FROM test_tbl;

-------------------------------    
SELECT COALESCE(tmp.id, 20) AS classification_id
FROM (
       SELECT tt.id,
              row_number() over(
       ORDER BY tt.id) AS row_num
       FROM test_tbl tt
     ) tmp
WHERE tmp.row_num =floor(random() * 10);
```

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it returns NULL occasionally

and I must add to this that it sometimes returns more than 1 rows, right?
in your sample data there are 6 rows, so the column `row_num` will have a value from 1 to 6.
This:

```
floor(random() * 10)
```

creates a random number from 0 up to 0.9999...
You should use:

```
floor(random() * 6 + 1)::int
```

to get a random integer from 1 to 6.
But this would not solve the problem, because the WHERE clause is executed once for each row, so there is a case that `row_num` will never match the created random number, so it will return **nothing**, or it will match more than once so it will return **more than 1 rows**.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=261a5f1bcf3a2bcf7786c196bfe1c253).
The proper (although sometimes not the most efficient) way to get a random row is:

```
SELECT id FROM test_tbl ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
```

Also check other links from SO, like:
[quick random row selection in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres/32023533)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply and correction, Actually, I tried to make the sample simple with removing some rows but forgot to update the floor number. BTW, you're right, it sometimes returns more than one row.

Comment: If you have a really large number of rows don't forget to search for other solutions too (like the link in my answer) because the *easy proper way* is not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You could select one row and order by `random()`, this way you are ensured to hit an existing row

```
select id
from test_tbl
order by random()
LIMIT 1;
```