# Is there a way to abstract the different forms of rand/random in different databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ignoring the inefficiency of the query is there an existing Rails wrapper for abstracting the differences between `rand()` across databases?

MySQL:

```
User.first(order: 'random()')
```

Postgres:

```
User.first(order: 'rand()')
```

I can create my own constant `RAND_STR` but was wondering if one already existed?

**Please note - this is not an efficiency question**

I know the query is inefficient I'm just wondering about the abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I used to have this problem however now it seems to have disappeared. Both SQLlite and Postgres are accepting `RANDOM()`. Not sure whether this is Rails' handiwork but whatever the reason it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like `User.offset(rand(User.count)).first`, but that would wind up executing two queries. Other than that, Rails doesn't have any built-in way to do this that I know of.

See [Rails 3: Get Random Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342270/rails-3-get-random-record)

Comment: Thanks - it's not how to get a random record I'm interested in though it's whether there's a Rails variable that stores the correct form of rand/random for the underlying database

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the rails docs show nothing about random records.