# Can't convert hash to integer - Trying to select random record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to select a random record, but the only working method seems like a horrible performance liability.

First attempt, using RANDOM function from Postgres - throws "Can't convert Hash into Integer"

```
   assigned_specialist = User.specialists.legal_for(coach_section).experienced_in(critique.discipline_id).first(:order => "RANDOM()")
   return assigned_specialist.id
```

Second attempt, using [offset method discussed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord) Also causes "Can't convert Hash into Integer"

```
  legal_specialists = User.specialists.legal_for(coach_section).experienced_in(critique.discipline_id)

  offset = rand(legal_specialists.count)
  assigned_specialist = legal_specialists.first(:offset => offset)
  return assigned_specialist.id
```

Final attempt, using array sample method, which works but seems bad.

```
  legal_specialists = User.specialists.legal_for(coach_section).experienced_in(critique.discipline_id)
  assigned_specialist = legal_specialists.sample
  return assigned_specialist.id
```

To be fair, there will only be about 20 specialists in the system, so the array sample method might never cause any issues, but I'd still like to understand what's going on here.

**Edit**: Here are the scopes I defined:

```
scope :specialists, where(:role_id => 2)
scope :legal_for, lambda { |coach_section| where("section_id != ?", coach_section) }
scope :experienced_in, lambda { |discipline_id|
  discipline = Discipline.find(discipline_id)
  discipline.users
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
User.specialists.legal_for(coach_section).experienced_in(critique.discipline_id).sample
```

It does query all the table, so you just have a shorter version ... wonder if there's a better way to do it!

Edit : Did you try this? It's supposed to work :

```
assigned_specialist = User.specialists.legal_for(coach_section).experienced_in(critique.discipline_id).order("RANDOM()").first
```

Take a look at the thread here : [Rails 3: Get Random Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342270/rails-3-get-random-record). It shows different ways to do it

Also look at this gem : https://github.com/spilliton/randumb
Seems to implement what you want to do, in a clean way

Edit : replace with this ?

```
scope :experienced_in, lambda { |discipline_id| joins(:habtm_models).where(habtm_models: {discipline_id: discipline_id})}
```

This way your scope will give you back an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. I assumed the `User` model `has_many :habtm_models` so replace with the real name!

Comment: I saw Zabba's comment on this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837385/376632), which is what initially made me concerned about the `sample` method. Would love it if a more experienced Rails dev could weigh in on the issue.

Comment: Edited my answer with more info!

Comment: Hmm, I tried your edit and now it's throwing `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x007ffc14e8a090>` Tried the Randumb gem earlier, but got the same hash|integer conversion problem. Thanks for the ideas though :)

Comment: May be because of the way you implemented your `legal_for` and `experienced_in` methods, are they `scopes` ?

Comment: Good idea, I added my scopes to the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18995/discussion-between-chris-fletcher-and-anthony-alberto)

Comment: As Anthony pointed out, my problem was that my :experienced_in scope was returning an Array instead of an ActiveRecord:Relation object. Thanks :)