# Most efficient way to get rails sample records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have about 2mil records in my db, and I need to frequently get random sets of x records. When my db consisted of about 50 records I used:

```
 Product.all.sample(5)
```

However this is EXTREMELY costly with my records count.

How can I efficiently find a small sample of records given the size of my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to get a much smaller set of Products. What you're doing now is costly because you're grabbing all Products first then selecting 5 of them at random with.

```
Product.limit(100).sample
```

This isn't ideal though because you'll return the same set of 100 Products.

Instead you can remove the `.sample` all together and just ask ActiveRecord for a random set of 5 Products

```
Product.order("RAND()").limit(5)
```

While you've move the performance issue out of Rails you've moved it into MySQL where 'RAND()' is [still pretty slow](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,185266,194715) for large datasets.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342270/rails-3-get-random-record) has a bunch on answers related to your problem that should prove useful.