# Add a global function available to all activerecord model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hey guys I want to add a function like this that returns a random record to all the active record models present in my Structure. How do I do this?

```
  def self.random
   if (c = count) != 0
    find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can use straight sql, I'll leave this here for future reference about adding class methods to all `ActiveRecord` objects.

```
class MyActiveRecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.random
    if (c = count) != 0
      find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
    end
  end
end
```

Now make sure each model that you want this class method in extends from `MyActiveRecordBase`

```
class Model < MyActiveRecordBase
end

class AnotherModel < MyActiveRecordBase
end
```

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks a lot, I will encounter an issue like this in the future thanks! Is there a way to specify the super class when creating the model using rails g?

Comment: @MadhanPadmanabhan I'm not sure. If I find a way, I will edit the answer and send you a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why the hassle?

```
Model.order("RANDOM()").first
```

There are better performance queries over at this question

[Rails 3: Get Random Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342270/rails-3-get-random-record)

Comment: Ok, making a fool of myself is checked with that! lol thanks a lot, I will make this the right answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in your /lib folder as models_methods.rb.

Create a method inside this module,

```
def rand(model)

   model.order("RANDOM()").first

end

def string_to_url(model)

  model.find(2).name.gsub([^A-Za-z0-9],/ /).downcase)

end
```

Include this module in all your models as "include ModelsMethods". This module can contain all the methods that you want to use across models.