# RANDOM() not working in Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was using the following method in my Rails 4 app to get random records in a model:

```
Model.order('RANDOM()').limit(5)
```

This broke after upgrading to Rails 4.0.2. It's always getting the most recent records. Any ideas why?

Comment: What does the rendered SQL query look like (from the log)?

Comment: SELECT "model".* FROM "model" ORDER BY created_at DESC, RANDOM() LIMIT 5

Comment: Do you have some default ordering scope on `Model` that you are not aware of now?

Comment: It orders by created_at DESC by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to remove the default scope from your model or call it like this:

```
Model.unscoped.order('RANDOM()').limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Model.all.sample(5)`

Comment: This may work okay for very small data sets, but the above will be very inefficient if Modal.all returns any significant number of rows as they will all be returned, objects instantiated, and only then will Array#sample randomly pick 5 of them.

Comment: [For more information of what Philip is referring to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12038506/877472)

Comment: Yup...got what you are saying. Thanks.