# Create a 'Random User' button on my Rails 3 web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, random

I want to have a button which goes to a random user on my site.   I am using the `friendly_id` gem so the URLs are, for example, `/users/dean` and I've also set it up so its `/dean`.

I'm guessing I would add something similar to this in my `routes.rb` file:

`match '/users/random'  => 'users#index'`

And then some extra code in the user controller?

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to _show_ a random user profile, or redirect to a random one?

Comment: I would like to redirect to a random user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this:

Define a class method `random` on User model (or in a module that's included into your model if you'd want to reuse it for other models later).

```
class User
  def self.random
    offset = rand(count)
    first(:offset => offset)
  end
end
```

[Other ways of getting a random record, if performance becomes an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord).

Add a `random` action in your UsersController like this

```
def random
  redirect_to User.random
end
```

And finally create a route

```
match '/users/random' => 'users#random'
```

Comment: Just a quick question, how can I do it so it ONLY shows users with content in `image_url`?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a specific action `random` in the user controller and localize the logic for choosing a user there.  Return a redirect to the route to that user from that action.  I would prefer this over complicating the index action with extra logic to handle a different action.

Comment: I see so in the routes, it would be something like `match '/users/random' => 'users#random'`?

Could you say what code I would need to put in the user controller? I'm only new to Rails and it will help others out :)