# Rails 3.1 Change the URL in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, controller

How do I Change the URL for the view in the controller.
In my controller I generate an ID which I want to display
in the URL of the browser when the view is rendered.

For example, when I enter / in my browser, it should redirect me
to /test/1. The ID is generated randomly by the controller.
So when I access / the 2nd time it could redirect me to /test/3.

I tried to do a match route in my routes.rb file.
But I couldn't find a solution.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'test/run'
root to: 'test#run'

match '/test/:id', to: 'test#run'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about that:

```
class TestController
  def show
    ...
  end

  def run
    redirect_to Test.random
  end
end
```

Of course, you have to write `random` scope for your Test model.
You may find helpful this question also - [Random record in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord)

P.S. I'm not sure that the `Test` is a good name for your model. It could be already used by ruby or rails.

Comment: I don't have a Test model. Test is only a controller that calls another model. But you answer helped me to improve my design. Is there no way to change the url from inside the controller?

Comment: It's possible with push state - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. Though it isn't supported by old versions of browsers. See how the github repository viewer works.

Comment: Thank you. But I need a way to do this without the use of java script.