# Iterate through db, and check for existence of a specific id

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a method which will  find me and an random 'article'. The thing is I have no clue how to iterate through the db, and not to get an exception in case of not found. 
How I think it would work(I know it isn't a rails-way but I have no other clue) Rand a number from Class.first to Class.last check if it exists(it is possible to be deleted) than return the object by the randomized id.

something like this:

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > def test
1.9.3p194 :011?>   until Task.exists?(x)
1.9.3p194 :012?>     print "hmmmmmm"
1.9.3p194 :013?>     x = rand(1..10)
1.9.3p194 :014?>     end
1.9.3p194 :015?>   end
```

(More of the specified criterias will be added when the method works this far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ActiveRecord than you have to catch RecordNotFound exception and call your method recursively. For other ORMs try to catch other exception.

```
def ran_find
  x = rand(1..100)
  Task.find(x)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  puts 'hmmmm'
  ran_find
end
```

Not the best implementation cause x values can be met more than one time.
But it works.

Comment: thank you. :) i'm new to rails and ebcause of the 2.x, 3.x versions even tutorials aren't clear enough somethimes.

Answer (score 1):

People like to use the ActiveRecord :offset option to grab a random record, since it avoids this RecordNotFound exception:

Taken from [Toby Hede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14971/toby-hede):
[Random record in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord)

> `offset = rand(Model.count)`
>
> `rand_record = Model.first(:offset => offset)`