# `Model.first(:order => 'random()')` always returns the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, random

When I try to do this:

```
questions = Array.new
2.times do
  question = Question.first(:order => 'random()')
  questions << question
end
```

and inspect the element:

```
raise questions.inspect
```

It returns an array including two same objects, but I expect two different objects in my `questions` array. What do I do wrong?

Comment: The error is probably in the implementation of `Question.first` -apparently it's not creating a new `Question` like you expect it to.

Comment: I suspect you're getting an object back when you call `Question.first` which just keeps the query around for later retrieval.

Comment: You can refer to this link for fetching random records: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a method on Question that returns a random record:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def self.random
    if (c = count) != 0
      find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
    end
  end

...

end
```

Then use:

```
questions = Array.new
2.times do
  question = Question.random
  questions << question
end
```