# Rails/ActiveRecord - finding N random items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following rudimentary piece of code in my model to return a random event:

```
def self.random
  Event.first(:offset => rand(Event.count))
end
```

I would like to modify the function so it returns **N** number of events.

I'm aware that `first` can take a number as a parameter, i.e. `Event.first(2)`, but how to combine it with random offset?

I.e. something like this

```
def self.random(n = 1)
  Event.first(n) # and offset??!!
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See also [Random record in ActiveRecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord). In particular, I prefer using the [randumb](https://github.com/spilliton/randumb) gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Stuarts method works perfectly by itself, it cannot be chained with many other ActiveRecord scopes.  I found the other method (using offset) that works with chaining:

```
  def self.random(number = 1)
    Event.offset(rand(Event.count - number+1)).first(number)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for returning `n` random records:

```
def self.random(n = 1)
  Event.order("RANDOM()").limit(n)
end
```

The `limit` method is actually called by `first` when you give it an Integer as the first argument, so you could also use `.first(n)` instead of `.limit(n)` if you prefer.

You may need to substitute `RAND()` instead of `RANDOM()` depending on your database system, consult the documentation for the exact method.