# Why is this method returning an active record relation rather than an object of the class type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class called Node.  In that class, I have a method:

```
def self.random
    self.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
end
```

I expected that to return a Node.  In fact, the stuff it outputs to the rails console looks like it is a Node.  Except it's not!

```
n = Node.random
n.class
```

gives me this:

```
=> ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Node
```

Comment: BTW same thing happens if I issue the order random command in IRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `ActiveRecord_Relation_Node` part of it is all about, but `.limit()` returns a scope (`ActiveRecord::Relation`), so that you can chain further scoped methods on to it. If you want the record itself use `.first` instead of `.limit(1)`.

Comment: awesome.  thanks.  I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord... answer by semanticart.... Model.first(:order => "RANDOM()") and it worked.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: The preferred syntax these days would be to chain them like: `Model.order("RANDOM()").first`, but what you have is equally valid.