# how to get a random record from the database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

i have a rails table called users and would love to know the best way to get random records from the database so it would be fast as if getting it like the normal

```
@users = User.all
```

THANKS....

Comment: what do u mean by 'random' records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random record in ActiveRecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord)

Comment: @Kunal S. Kushwah i mean not in an order like descending, ascending , created at ..... just in random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Get 5 random users
@users = User.order('RAND()').limit(5)
```

Note that the `RAND()` (MySQL) function is called `RANDOM()` in PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Comment: will this be very efficient if for instance i have 5000 users and different people at different locations are trying to get random users from the application?

Comment: I think this is the most efficient way possible.

Comment: thanks alot will stick to your answer, but can i cache it and how?