# How would I make a link that takes you to a random article on the site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

It would be exactly like Wikipedia's "Random Article" button.  Takes you to a random webpage on the site.

Comment: I would do something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= button_to "Random Article", article_path(random_article) %>

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def random_article
      Article.order("RAND()").first.pluck(:id)
   end
end
```

With help from this article: [Random record in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord)

Answer (score -1):

Some more information would make this much easier to answer, but there are a few ways to do it. The best, in my opinion, would be something like this:

routes.rb:

```
resources :articles do
  get :random_article
end
#OR
get 'random_article' => 'some_controller#random_article', as: 'random_article'
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def random_article
  redirect_to article_path(Article.all.sample.id)
end
```

And on your page:

```
<%= link_to 'Random Article', random_article_path %>
```