# NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass): in Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone help with this?Thanks in advance for your reply.

In app/controllers/heats_controller.rb, the code is as below:

```
class HeatsController < ApplicationController
  def add_car
    Pusher[params[:sendTo]].trigger('addCar', car_params)
    head :ok
  end

  def index
    @heats = Heat.all
    render json: @heats
  end

  def new

    race = Race.all.sample

    render json: { start_time: Time.now.to_s,
                   race_id: race.id,
                   text: race.passage }
  end

  def show
    @heat = Heat.find(params[:id])
  end

  def start_game
    Pusher[params[:sendTo]].trigger('initiateCountDown', start_heat_params)
    head :ok
  end

  def update_board
    Pusher[params[:channel]].trigger('updateBoard', car_params)
    head :ok
  end

  private
  def heat_params
    params.require(:heat).permit(:race_id)
  end

  def car_params
    params.permit(:racer_id,
                  :racer_name,
                  :return_to,
                  :progress,
                  :racer_img,
                  :wpm,
                  :channel,
                  :sendTo)
  end

  def start_heat_params
    params.permit(:channel, :race_id, :text, :timer)
  end
end
```

In app/models/heat.rb, the code is as below:

```
class Heat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
  has_many :racer_stats
end
```

Any help will be appreciated ,thank you

---

Error:

```
Processing by HeatsController#new as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/heats_controller.rb:18:in `new'
```

Comment: Add your rails server log .. in the question too

Comment: What is `sample` in `Race.all.sample`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Race.all.sample` does not work.

Maybe you have no records in `races` table at all.

Also, try this to retrieve random record (for Rails 4):

```
def new
   offset = rand(Race.count)
   Race.offset(offset).first
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
def new
  ... race_id: race.id ...
end
```

`race` doesn't have any data, so calling `.id` on it won't work. You're also calling `Race.all.sample` (very bad), which means you've *probably* got no records in your `Race` model.

---

If you want to pick a random record, you should [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577054/1143732) to pull one:

```
def new
   race = Race.order("RAND()").first #-> MYSQL
   render json: { start_time: Time.now.to_s, race_id: race.id, text: race.passage } unless race.nil?
end
```

Comment: sorry, if I use postgresql, it will be the same?

Comment: Just change `RAND()` to `RANDOM()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
render json: { start_time: Time.now.to_s,
                   race_id: race.try(:id),
                   text: race.try(:passage) }
```

This would fix the whiny nil error if your .sample returns nil.
But I agree that all.sample is bad practice.