# Not able to display random images below product image in Ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, foreign-keys

I want to be able to show 3 random product images below a product image, so far I've inserted this code below the product image as seen in the `views/products/show.html.erb`

`views/products/show.html.erb`

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block" > 

    <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive"  %> 
    #This is the Product image#
    ##EDITED ##
     #Below is the codesnippet for three products to appear##
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="col-sm-2 center-block " >

<%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:thumb), class: "img-responsive" %>
        <% end %>

    <div class="product_description">

      <h5><%= link_to product.title, product %></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in my `products_controller.rb` I've the code, I believe the problem is to be found in the `@products`, but I'm not sure what it is. Please can someone advice me.

`products_controller.rb`

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def show
   @meta_title = "Concept Store #{@product.title}"
   @meta_description = @product.description
   @products = Product.all ###EDITED###
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_product
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd, :price_isl, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug)
  end
end
```

My models `Products` and `Categories`have relations

`product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :label

has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

`category.rb`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :products, :dependent => :nullify

 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

Comment: I don't think `each_slice` does what you think. [Check out the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
@products = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @product.image})
```

- `@products` okay, presumably a collection of `Product` instances
- `Category.joins(:products)` uhhh, this returns instances of `Category`
- `where(products: { id: @product.image })` wait, filter by products with an ID matching `@product.image`, which is ostensibly a string url or file path

All together: `@products =` an array of categories with associated products where the numeric ID matches a particular string on a particular product.

My recommendation for you would be to [review the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) with particular attention to the [ActiveRecord Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: thanks, I was complicating things to much. I ended with just doing `@products = Product.all` still I have to figure out how to make only 3 image appear randomly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752231/random-record-in-activerecord