# Displaying random products in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, random, many-to-many

In a app I'm building, a customer selects a product and in the `products/show.html.erb` he is supposed to be able to see related products in a below div.

category.rb and product.rb are related:

`cateory.rb
    has_many :products, :dependent => :nullify`

`product.rb
  belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :label`

So Im thinking the best way to do that is to display random products from the same category as the selected product `belongs_to`?

At the moment this what I have in the `def show`  line in the `products_controller.rb`

```
@products_rand = Product.offset(offset).limit(6)
```

I need it to grab only products in the same category as the selected product?

`products_controller.rb`

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


     def show
      offset = rand(100)
       @meta_title = "Mypage #{@product.title}"
       @meta_description = @product.description
      @products_rand = Product.offset(offset).limit(6)
     end

    private
     def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
     end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug)
    end


 end
```

And the random products are displayed in this the `views/products/show.html.erb`

```
  <div class="row product-teaser">

  <h4 class="text-center teaser-text"> Products from same category </h4>
   <% @products_rand.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 center-block product-thumbs-product-view" >

       <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
         <%= image_tag product.image.url, :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
       <% end %>

          <h5 class="text-center"><%= link_to product.title, product, class: "text-center" %></h5>

      </div>
      <% end %>

  </div>
```

Here is a link to previous question about this [Not able to display random images below product image in Ruby on rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920636/not-able-to-display-random-images-below-product-image-in-ruby-on-rails-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following (for **Postgres/SQLite**):

```
@products_rand = Product.where(category_id: @product.category_id).order("RANDOM()").limit(6)
```

Or the following for **MySQL**:

```
@products_rand = Product.where(category_id: @product.category_id).order("RAND()").limit(6)
```

Comment: Thanks, the postgres version works.  Is it possible to exclude the selected product from the random products?

Comment: You might be able to use `where.not.(id: @product.id)`

Comment: I have never used `where.not.`, should it come instead of `where`?